# Enter a contact in Telegram with python-telegram-bot or telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, invoke, telethon

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
import telebot
from telethon import TelegramClient,client
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import GetContactsRequest, 
Import ContactsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser, InputPhoneContact

contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id = 0, phone = "+12345678", 
first_name="ABC", last_name="abc")
result = client.invoke(ImportContactsRequest([contact], replace=True))
print(f"1: {contact}\n2: {result}")
```

I can not explain the reason for this error according to the writing program
instruction, but it does not answer

Error is :

```
    `AttributeError: module 'telethon.client' has no attribute 'invoke`
```

Comment: Please, format your code in order to be readable, so that users can understand it and provide useful answers.

Comment: Yes you are right
This was the first time
I'm sorry